# Headers are missing - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I try to install https://github.com/episage/SharpNFC/ , according to readme file.

I don't have internet access on my VM so I move files instead of wget.

So I move the file `libnfc-1.7.0.tar.bz2` to my Ubuntu. After that `tar xvjf libnfc-1.7.1.tar.bz2` and `cd libnfc-1.7.1` - all fine.

But when I do `./configure --prefix=/usr` I got this:

```
libnfc-1.7.1/
libnfc-1.7.1/install-sh
libnfc-1.7.1/CMakeLists.txt
libnfc-1.7.1/aclocal.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/INSTALL
libnfc-1.7.1/test/
libnfc-1.7.1/test/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/test/test_dep_passive.c
libnfc-1.7.1/test/test_device_modes_as_dep.c
libnfc-1.7.1/test/test_register_endianness.c
libnfc-1.7.1/test/test_dep_active.c
libnfc-1.7.1/test/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/test/test_access_storm.c
libnfc-1.7.1/test/run-test.sh
libnfc-1.7.1/test/test_register_access.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc.conf.sample
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/libtool.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/ltversion.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/readline.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/ltoptions.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/ltsugar.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/lt~obsolete.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/libnfc_check_libusb.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/libnfc_drivers.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/m4/libnfc_check_pcsc.m4
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/config_posix.h.cmake
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/config_windows.h.cmake
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/FixBundle.cmake.in
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/modules/
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/modules/UseDoxygen.cmake
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/modules/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/modules/FindPCSC.cmake
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/modules/LibnfcDrivers.cmake
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/modules/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/modules/FindPCRE.cmake
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/modules/FindLIBUSB.cmake
libnfc-1.7.1/cmake/modules/COPYING-CMAKE-SCRIPTS
libnfc-1.7.1/configure
libnfc-1.7.1/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/CMakeLists.txt
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-utils.h
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-list.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.1
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-utils.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-jewel.1
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-jewel.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-mfultralight.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/jewel.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-read-forum-tag3.1
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-list.1
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/mifare.h
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-mfultralight.1
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-relay-picc.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-read-forum-tag3.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-mfclassic.1
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-scan-device.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/mifare.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-relay-picc.1
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-mfclassic.c
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/jewel.h
libnfc-1.7.1/utils/nfc-scan-device.1
libnfc-1.7.1/README-Windows.txt
libnfc-1.7.1/depcomp
libnfc-1.7.1/Doxyfile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/config.h.in
libnfc-1.7.1/ar-lib
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/windows.h
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/linux/
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/linux/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/linux/blacklist-libnfc.conf
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/linux/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/libnfc/
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/libnfc/arygon.conf.sample
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/libnfc/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/libnfc/pn532_uart_on_rpi.conf.sample
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/libnfc/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/libnfc/pn532_via_uart2usb.conf.sample
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/err.h
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/version.rc.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/sys/
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/sys/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/sys/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/sys/select.h
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/stdlib.c
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/unistd.h
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/libnfc/
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/libnfc/buses/
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/libnfc/buses/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/libnfc/buses/uart.c
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/libnfc/buses/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/libnfc/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/libnfc/log-internal.c
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/libnfc/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/win32/nfc.def
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/devd/
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/devd/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/devd/pn53x.conf
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/devd/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/udev/
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/udev/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/udev/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/udev/42-pn53x.rules
libnfc-1.7.1/config.guess
libnfc-1.7.1/README
libnfc-1.7.1/config.sub
libnfc-1.7.1/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/missing
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/uart.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/usbbus.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/uart.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/spi.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/spi.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/usbbus.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/i2c.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/empty.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/buses/i2c.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/CMakeLists.txt
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/conf.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/nfc-emulation.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/log.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/log-internal.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/mirror-subr.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/chips/
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/chips/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/chips/pn53x.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/chips/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/chips/pn53x.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/chips/pn53x-internal.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/log-internal.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/iso14443-subr.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/log.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/nfc-device.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/nfc-internal.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/nfc-internal.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/iso7816.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/target-subr.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/nfc.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/arygon.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/pn532_spi.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/pn532_uart.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/acr122_pcsc.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/pn53x_usb.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/acr122s.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/acr122_usb.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/acr122s.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/pn53x_usb.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/pn532_i2c.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/acr122_pcsc.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/pn532_spi.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/pn532_i2c.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/arygon.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/pn532_uart.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/acr122_usb.h
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/conf.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/target-subr.c
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/mirror-subr.h
libnfc-1.7.1/NEWS
libnfc-1.7.1/COPYING
libnfc-1.7.1/ChangeLog
libnfc-1.7.1/configure.ac
libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc.pc.in
libnfc-1.7.1/Doxyfile
libnfc-1.7.1/ltmain.sh
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-poll.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-emulate-tag.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/CMakeLists.txt
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-diagnose.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-mfsetuid.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-sam.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-relay.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-anticol.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-emulate-forum-tag2.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-tamashell.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-poll.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-emulate-tag.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-emulate-uid.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-tamashell-scripts/
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-tamashell-scripts/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-tamashell-scripts/ReadMobib.sh
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-tamashell-scripts/UltraLightReadWrite.cmd
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-tamashell-scripts/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-tamashell-scripts/ReadNavigo.sh
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-tamashell-scripts/UltraLightRead.cmd
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-sam.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-dep-initiator.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/doc/
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/doc/quick_start_example1.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/doc/quick_start_example2.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-anticol.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-dep-initiator.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-tamashell.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-dep-target.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-dep-target.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-mfsetuid.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/pn53x-diagnose.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-emulate-uid.c
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-relay.1
libnfc-1.7.1/examples/nfc-emulate-forum-tag2.c
libnfc-1.7.1/include/
libnfc-1.7.1/include/CMakeLists.txt
libnfc-1.7.1/include/nfc/
libnfc-1.7.1/include/nfc/CMakeLists.txt
libnfc-1.7.1/include/nfc/nfc-emulation.h
libnfc-1.7.1/include/nfc/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/include/nfc/nfc-types.h
libnfc-1.7.1/include/nfc/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/include/nfc/nfc.h
libnfc-1.7.1/include/Makefile.am
libnfc-1.7.1/include/Makefile.in
libnfc-1.7.1/AUTHORS
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Install$ cd libnfc-1.7.1
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Install/libnfc-1.7.1$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking stdio.h usability... yes
checking stdio.h presence... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking linux/spi/spidev.h usability... yes
checking linux/spi/spidev.h presence... yes
checking for linux/spi/spidev.h... yes
checking linux/i2c-dev.h usability... yes
checking linux/i2c-dev.h presence... yes
checking for linux/i2c-dev.h... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for usleep... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for log flag... yes
checking for conffiles flag... yes
checking for envvars flag... yes
checking for debug flag... no
checking which drivers to build... default drivers
checking for documentation request... no
checking for libusb... no
checking for libusb... no
checking for libusb-config... no
checking usb.h usability... no
checking usb.h presence... no
checking for usb.h... no
configure: error: The libusb headers are missing
```

What can I do please?

Answer (score 4):

The error message says `The libusb headers are missing`.  So install the package that contains them.   On ubuntu, development headers are usually in a package with a name ending in `-dev`.  So, if a package called `libusb` contains the run-time libraries for libusb, then `libusb-dev` will contain the development headers.

```
apt-get install libusb-dev
```

repeat as appropriate for any other missing header files.

Comment: apt-get install must internet access , i not have(on the vm i want this pack) . i have another vm with ubuntu with internet access.